# quantidade de caracteres no Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Alguém disse que o tipo TEXT permite 65535 bytes, mas eu não consigo postar mais que 10.000 caracteres, o que estou fazendo de errado?

---

Essa é a minha Tabela

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cad_materia`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_materia` (
  `php_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `php_titulo` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `php_thumb` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `php_texto` longtext NOT NULL,
  `php_categoria` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `php_autor` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `php_data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `php_chave` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `url` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cod_user` char(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`php_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

Bom eu sou uma iniciante, no text eu não coloquei valor nenhum, o erro dá quando vou postar o texto co site,

Comment: Boa pergunta. Qual é a estrutura da tabela? Como está inserindo os valores? Testou a inserção diretamente no banco de dados para garantir que é realmente ele que está truncando o conteúdo? Aliás, está truncando ou dá erro durante o processo? Qual erro?

Comment: Basicamente por que byte e caractere são coisas diferentes. Em utf8 multiplique por três, e em utf8mb4 multiplique por 4 o espaço reservado pelo MySQL - tem posts mencionando isso no site, se localizar já linko aqui